# How can I connect a 3-pin fan to RAMPS 1.6?

Tags: ramps-1.6, fans

I have a 3-pin (red, black, white) fan, and I need to cool my RAMPS 1.6 board with this fan. How can I connect the fan to the board and turn it on/off?

Comment: As far as connecting, [this answer explains how](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/523052/212071).

Comment: @bkarpuz Connect only the wires Red and Black to 12V line input; there is not any AUX 12V output on this board like Ramps 1.4.